# Android Observer is being deleted after being notified once?

Tags: java, android, observer-pattern

I have a simple Android application that has an Activity with an Observable object, foo, inside of it. I have a private inner class implementing Observer in my activity that updates the GUI with the argument passed to update. I attach the Observer with foo.addObserver when creating the activity.

However, my observer is only notified once, then it receives no more updates. I've stepped into foo and my observer is deleted when it tries to send out a 2nd notification. Has anybody experienced this before? What could be causing this? I don't know how to troubleshoot this any further. This seems so simple. There's probably something outside of this that I'm doing that is causing this? If anybody has any ideas, I can reveal more of my application.

Relevant code for this is below (sans parameters and scope)

**Activity**

```
onCreate
  ...
  foo = new Foo();
  foo.addObserver( new FooObserver() );
  ...

class FooObserver implements Observer {
  update()
    updateGUI();
```

**Foo**

```
arbitraryMethod()
   ...
   setChanged();
   notifyObservers( argument );
```

Comment: I can tell you for sure that nothing in android suppose to "delete" your observer after first time.  when you says "deleted" do you mean that your observer equals null after the first time?  anyway - for locating were your bug is - you must post more of your code.

Comment: Okay, after thinking about my code more to further explain it, I've realized that I'm referencing different instances of Foo in different places and not treating the class as a singleton (or using the same object). Obviously, this was the cause of the issue. What should I do with this question? Should I just delete it?

Comment: I suggest you to answer your own question with explanation about what was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (embarrassing) problem I was having is that I had multiple instances of Foo and was only registering the listener one a specific instance of the object without remembering that I have created multiple instances of the object, which is why the array of Observers was empty after the first update; I was looking at a different object!

There are many solutions to this, but the one that works in my case is to make the object a singleton.